# Discord.js v12.5.3 is there a way I could add role(s) on interaction?

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am 90% done with my application system but I am missing one thing

I am trying to add roles when someone applies,
I tried doing it with this

```js
let teamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "761996603434598460")

member.roles.add(teamRole)
```

but it does not add the roles (I don't get any errors doing it)

**is there any way I can do it with the code below for the interaction?**

```js
client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", async (interaction) => {
    // If component type is a button
    if (interaction.data.component_type === 2) {
        const guildId = interaction.guild_id;
        const userId = interaction.member.user.id;
        const buttonId = interaction.data.custom_id;
        const member = client.guilds.resolve(guildId).member(userId);
        if (buttonId == "send_application") {
            // Reply to an interaction, so we don't get "This interaction failed" error
            client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                data: {
                    type: 4,
                    data: {
                        content: "I have started the application process in your DM's.",
                        flags: 64 // make the message ephemeral
                    }
                }
            });
```

I would appreciate the help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a role it should be a snowflake value, so you should add using the ID and not the role it self

Incorrect:

```js
let teamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "761996603434598460")

member.roles.add(teamRole)
```

Correct:

```js
// using the ID Directly
member.roles.add('761996603434598460')
```

Comment: found an issue with my code after doing this haha, it adds roles to all the applications when accepted, ill have to look into handling user interactions differently or just upgrade to d.js v13 lmao

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean , anyways you can contact me on discord UltraX#0001